# Ajax.Actionlink forwarding to Get method while setting httpmethod to post

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Controller's get and post method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        SoSession.Authenticate("pierre", "pierre");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CompanySearch model)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Companies",new{searchString=model.SearchString});

    }
```

in view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Company"))
{
    <div class="input-block-level">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)
         @Ajax.ActionLink(
             "Submit",
             "Index", 
             new{}, 
             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv" }) 
    </div>


}

<div id="partialDiv"></div>
```

**Problem**
Whenever user clicks submit link i get forwarded to get method and not post method. How do i forward the call to post method of my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the unobutrusive ajax library file (and it's dependencies (jQuery)) loaded to your view properly. If you do not have this file loaded to your page, Clicking on the link produced by `Ajax.ActionLink` helper method will do a `GET` request instead of the asynchronous `POST` you were expecting.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had it loaded, my problem was i had ajax library on top on jquery library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to use an ajax form:

```
@using Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)
}
```

If you include the ajax js libraries that should work.

Comment: The first parameter, isn't it supposed to be name of the method in controller?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming you had a submit method since that is how you had your action link set up. The parameters in order are: action, controller, form method, ajax options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery for the partial load although the controller would return a partial. I do agree with mayabelle that Ajax.BeginForm() is another route to take.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Companies(string searchString)
{
    return this.PartialView("MyView", MyObject)
}
```

inside of the cshtml javascript:

```
var searchString = $("#SearchString").val();
$("#partialDiv").load('@Url.Content("~/Home/Companies/")' + searchString, function(){ DoSomething(); });
```